# Proposing a new sub-tag: diablo-3-auction

Tags: discussion, tags

With the recent promotion over I have actually been going over and reading all the questions we have amassed and I have found that there are a large collection of questions specifically about the auction house. A quick query for "[diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) auction" returned 162 results with a fair share of [closed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed) questions and some that mention it in an off-handed (like the barbarian build one).

A quick poke in the channel of those who were active pushed this thought forward enough to tag [a single question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70868) with the new tag so I could get it all set up and then this post here so people could give some thoughts back on pushing this tag out to appropriate questions. I do not think all 162 need this tag but I would be surprised if we did not end up with a quantity rivaling the current class sub-tags.

So the new tag would be [diablo-3-auction](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-auction) to keep its size in check. I have put in a very short and sweet wiki description and invite the community to poke it around until it is fitting or just state that this tag would not be useful.

Comment: I feel like this could encourage people to list their auctions.  If there is a tag, people will be sure to use it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this meta thread when I rolled back the change on the question you mention (thought I was ending a roll-back war). That said, I do not think the tag will lead to useful questions.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot citation needed?

Comment: @badp For which part?  The first is purely speculation.  The second I have seen time and time again.

Comment: I agree with @OrigamiRobot here, it would 'invite' users to post their active auctions... not good.  Also, badp just likes to say things from Wikipedia, I don't think he actually wanted a citation.

Comment: I guess I am just not seeing how it would invite people to post their auctions here.. That is just not a leap of thought I can make.

Comment: @James New people think this is a forum. If they see diablo-3-auction it could make them think they can post auctions. badp's suggestion addresses *that* concern, but I still don't think it's a very useful tag.

Answer (score 6):

Just do it. And I'd rather have the tag read [diablo-3-auction-house](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-auction-house), it still fits in the size limits; this should also dribble Origami's concerns and perhaps Raven's too.

Comment: Yeah this is actually fairly hard to Just Do It when people keep rolling back the changes :D